# xcode change bundle identifier to overwrite old app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have a old version of an app created by someone else with a different bundle id, I would like to update this so users who have downloaded it will get the new version of the app.

Would it just be a case of changing the bundle id in xcode and uploading it over the old app?

How would I do this in xcode, can I copy my project so I can rename it?

For future updates would I need to update two versions? could I link them somehow to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If you will change the bundle identifier of the existing application, your application will not be overwritten to the existing users, it will be seen as a different application on app store.***

For Application update to reflect into the existing application of existing users, you must use the same bundle identifier with the increased version number and other changes, if any.

Comment: For customers that have download the old app - does this mean I will have to have two versions live. One for old customers and one for new. I don't want to keep having to update two versions,

Comment: No, old customers will see the update option in app store, once they click their existing application will be updated. 

When you update your application on app store, your old application will be overwritten with the new one.

Comment: How would I do that in xcode? Would I need to create a new target?

Comment: No, you just need to increase the version number and also create a new version of your application with same version (One that you have increased/used in Xcode) on [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/). 

For further guidelines, you can check this [link](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev442d7f2ca) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

While updating the app the only mandatory thing you have to do is to increase the bundle build identifier and app version identifier and if you have changed something in your app that your users should know than you have to write it in the description and you are good to go.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking, I would to update the two versions of the app in the future? Could I link them somehow?

Comment: if i am getting you right than you are asking that you will upload two more updates of your app in future. If this is the case than you dont need to link them just increase the version number and your same app will be updated on app store.